# Use MFOC on Mifare with arduino and MFRC522

Tags: arduino, mifare

I have a Mifare RFID Tag and I know the key A.

But I need the Key B.

How can I use MFOC on arduino with MFRC522?

I have been researching but did not find any reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MFOC relies on libnfc. There is a libnfc version out there to make Arduino boards compatible with libnfc.

http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Libnfc:Arduino

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pn532-rfid-nfc/libnfc

They have specific software on the Arduino and a patched version of libnfc. They rely on a PN532 reader that is not the same as MFRC522.

There is a similar library for with MFRC522 support but it is not working.

https://github.com/ehkom/libnfc

MFOC is also not going to directly run on an arduino.

Comment: Thanks, I have been researching on how to run MFOC via the Arduino (not directly) on Windows. But I only find linux ressources. Do you know if it's possible and where I can find documentation about it?

Comment: They both (libnfc&MFOC) work under Windows with Cygwin. You will have to compile it yourself, I do not think there is ready to run binaries available.